# With MavensMate I get the error Could not update lightning components: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, mavensmate, sublime

I am using Sublime Text and MavensMate.

I created a new lightning component in the dev console and then added it to the package in MavensMate.  Usually at this point I have to clean my project or I get the error.  Now nothing seems to fix it.

When I try to compile my component I get "[ERROR]: Could not update lightning components: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined."

I have tried:

1. deleting the .lightning file in config
2. cleaning the project
3. creating a new project
4. refreshing the metadata and updating the project.

none of them helped.

I manually added the component, css, controller, and helper to the .lightning file and that worked until I updated my project and then it lost the updates to the .lightning file.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get my component to compile?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your problem, however mavens mate is no longer maintained. You should look into vscode with the Salesforce extensions. You do not have to use scratch orgs to develop and can connect to sandboxes

Comment: or use an ide like intellij/illuminated cloud; works great w/ scratch orgs as well as sandboxes

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have an answer to your problem, however mavens mate is no longer maintained. You should look into vscode with the Salesforce extensions. You do not have to use scratch orgs to develop and can connect to sandboxes – Programmatic Jul 15 at 20:55

this is exactly what I had to do.  I have shifted to VSCode and found that most of what I do in sublime works in vscode with extensions.